# jQuery Show/Hide divs using same class not working because of html.push?

Tags: class, html, toggle, push, show-hide

The object is to Show-Hide text located under their respective Titles, so a User reads the title and shows or hides text belonging to that title if the User wants to read more.

I tried whatever I could find so far on here, we're talking dynamically setting text coming from a spreadsheet, can't use IDs, must work with `.class`, must be missing something, I have this piece of code:

... `html.push('<div class="comments">' + comment + '</div></div></div>');`

but when I try this [Show-Hide code](http://jsfiddle.net/6GRJr/) nothing happens, even if the error console shows nothing. Basically I want to Show-Hide the `.comments` class divs with a show-hide toggle link located under each of them. I say *them* because the `.comments` divs are reproduced dynamically while extracting text coming from Google spreadsheet cells/row (one `.comments` div per spreadsheet row). I tried `.next`, `child` and `parent` but they all divorced me so I dunno looks like a dynamic issue. So far I only managed to globally toggle all divs to a visible or hidden state but I need to toggle independantly individual divs.

I prefer a jQuery solution but whatever worked so far was achieved with native javascript.

Note: If a cross-browser truncate function which would append a more-less link after a number of words (var) in each `.comments` divs would be easier to implement then I would gladly take that option. Thx for any help, remember I am still learning lol!

Comment: `html.push('<div style="display:none;" class="comments">' + comment + '</div><button class="toggle">more</button></div></div>');` did not work with `$('button.toggle').click(function() { $(this).prev('div').toggle(); });` either. I checked with the alert() as Scott E mentioned below and it gave a 0. Hmmmm.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on an entirely JS UI project and have brought myself to using $('', { properties }).appendTo(BaseElement) to work best for adding HTML elements because it appropriately manipulates the DOM every time.

If you are having good luck with push elsewhere, however, breakpointing on the line where you do your $('.class').hide() and see what $('.class').length is. Alternately, you can just add alert($('.class').length) to your code if you are unable to breakpoint the code. If it is 0, then your elements have not been properly added to the DOM. Changing to append will ensure they are part of the DOM and therefore targetable via JQuery.

Comment: Yes, I am also working on a JS UI and its concerning google gadgets [link](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/spreadsheets/gadgets/). This is way above me for now but I have to find a solution. I think any way of retreiving cell data will do, push or without push, but I am not at a level to fully comprehend how to go about yet. I will try the append thingy as you mentioned. Thx for pointers.

Comment: No problem. I have been using the .appendTo method for months now and it works like a charm. For your example above, the proper code would be:

`$('<div/>', {'style': 'display: none;', 'class': 'comments', 'html': comment}).click(function() { }).appendTo(html);`

or something in that arena.

Comment: Ahh the DOM! Got something working by replacing relevant `html.push` instances with `$jq('<div class="expandable">' + comment + '</div></div></div>').appendTo(texte);`, with `texte` being the variable which sets the html into the targeted divs. `var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();` allows me to combine the two libraries used. Discovered the use `each()` in order to seek and apply a clickable function to headers which allows to expand-collapse their `next()` hidden content. The use of `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` closing `each()` is needed in my case. Thx for `appendTo()` tip Scott E!